# 06531- "Reference to uninitialized collection" -Dynamic Matrix in PLSQL oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to make a matrix in plsql oracle, but I'm a beginner in plsql and I have some problem to compile a simple code.
This is my simple code

```
declare
    type proof IS RECORD(
        val number,
        des varchar2(30)
    );
    
    type nested_proof is table of proof;
    matrix nested_proof;
begin

    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
          matrix(i).val := i;
          matrix(i).des :='test'||i;
    END LOOP;
    
    FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(matrix(i).val||' - '||matrix(i).des);
    END LOOP;
        
end;
```

This is just an example to understand how it works a matrix in plsql. My target is to make a dynamic matrix with two columns and undefined number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things (both marked in code below); without the 1st, you have *reference to uninitialized collection*. Without the 2nd, you have *subscript beyond count*.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2      type proof IS RECORD(
  3          val number,
  4          des varchar2(30)
  5      );
  6
  7      type nested_proof is table of proof;
  8      matrix nested_proof := nested_proof();       --> this
  9  begin
 10
 11      FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
 12            matrix.extend;                         --> this
 13            matrix(i).val := i;
 14            matrix(i).des :='test'||i;
 15      END LOOP;
 16
 17      FOR i IN 1..3 LOOP
 18            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(matrix(i).val||' - '||matrix(i).des);
 19      END LOOP;
 20
 21  end;
 22  /
1 - test1
2 - test2
3 - test3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your solution, and your explanation of your solution